# Cocoa Swift: how to automate click on html using javascript using in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

I'm loading html page inside of WKWebView and I need to click on a link. For example. loading `apple.com`

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    webView.load(urlString: "https://www.apple.com")
}
```

and locating the links to click:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('cta-links')[0].innerHTML") { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
        if result != nil{
            print("code with links \(result)")
        }
    }

}
```

The output I'll get is:

```
<a href="/us/shop/goto/buy_iphone/iphone_xr" class="cta more" aria-label="Buy now with trade in" data-analytics-title="buy now with trade-in" data-analytics-region="buy">Buy<span class="visuallyhidden">with trade in</span></a>

<a href="/us/shop/goto/trade_in" class="cta more" aria-label="Learn more about trade in" data-analytics-title="Learn more about trade-in" data-analytics-region="learn more">Learn more</a>
```

But my question to you guys is how can I click on of those links for example on this link:

```
<a href="/us/shop/goto/trade_in" class="cta more" aria-label="Learn more about trade in" data-analytics-title="Learn more about trade-in" data-analytics-region="learn more">Learn more</a>
```

There is a way to click on that link either with javascript or any other way in swift?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click the following link, you need to identify it in some way, for sake of example I will use the label, as the class is not unique, ideally you would have an ID.

```
<a href="/us/shop/goto/trade_in" class="cta more" aria-label="Learn more about trade in" data-analytics-title="Learn more about trade-in" data-analytics-region="learn more">Learn more</a>
```

In your script you will then need to find this element, you can use querySelectorAll() do to this.

```
let elementToClick = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Learn more about trade in"]')[0];
```

And then in your script, call the [DOM click()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) method

```
elementToClick.click();
```

This will emulate a click and redirect you to the path given in the href.

Comment: what you mean with "myCheck"?

Comment: This is simply the ID i gave your href, I am then grabbing that element by ID in the javascript and then using the .click() method on it

Comment: the problem is the urls doesn't have an ID per code sniped I post. They have a class

Comment: you will need a unique identifier of some sort, otherwise you will trigger a click on all of the links with the class name you specify

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: because following your example `document.getElementsByClassName('cta more').click()` this doesn't work

Comment: `cta` is one class, `more` is another class, you can't select by both classes in the one query

Comment: can you please post an example of how to select on of the link urls?